# Cauchy Riemann Equations for $h(z)=|z|^2z^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

A past exam question I have come across is...

Is the following function differentiable on $\mathbb{C}$

$h(z)=|z|^2z^2$

I have calculated $u(x,y)=x^4-y^4$ and $v(x,y)=2x^3y+2xy^3$

I then have

$\frac{du}{dx}=4x^3,$

$\frac{dv}{dx}=6x^2y+2y^3$

$ \frac{dv}{dy}=-4y^3$

$ \frac{dv}{dy}=2x^3+6xy^2$

hence these do not satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations as $\frac{du}{dx} \neq\frac{dv}{dy}, -\frac{dv}{dx} \neq \frac{du}{dy}$

Is this enough to show that its not differentiable on $\mathbb{C}$??

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Analytic functions must satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations.  These do not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Though a simpler derivation (though I am not sure whether your course has covered the notation) is the following.

Writing $z = x+iy$ and $\bar{z} = x - iy$. Formally $z$ and $\bar{z}$ form a coordinate system of $\mathbb{C}$ (in the sense that $(x,y)$ has two component and $(z,\bar{z})$ has two components, this can be made more precise in the context of complex geometry, but just take this as a given for now) by pretending that $z$ and $\bar{z}$ are "real" numbers. The usual change of variables formula allows one to write $\partial_x, \partial_y$ in terms of $\partial_z$ and $\partial_{\bar{z}}$.

Now here's the kicker: the Cauchy-Riemann equations can be written as 
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} = 0 $$
in this coordinate system.

Your function $h$ can be written as
$$ h(z,\bar{z}) = z^3 \bar{z} $$
and hence
$$ \frac{\partial h}{\partial \bar{z}} = z^3 \neq 0$$ 
when $z \neq 0$. This shows that your function does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations and so that it is not holomorphic.

Comment: No, $|z|^2 = z\bar{z}$ by definition. (Though I did make a typo, which I corrected.)

Answer (score 0):

More easily, you can choose two different directions, say horizontal and vertical directions at the point $1$ and calculate their derivatives. Then you will see that they are not equal and hence it is not differentiable.